# ompr: Is there a mistake in the solve_model expression?

Tags: r, optimization

I am using ompr to optimse some schedule.

```
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)
library(tidyverse)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ROI.plugin.symphony)

library(readxl)
library(reshape2)

personen <- c("A","B","C")
geräte <- c("a","b","c")
wochentage <- c("Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch")

# Definition von den skills (wer (A-C) kann welches Geräte (a-c) bedienen)
skill <- matrix(c(1,1,3,2,0,1,3,0,1), nrow=3)

# Definition von anwesenheit (wer ist wann anwesend)
anwesenheit <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1),nrow=3)

colnames(skill) <- geräte
rownames(skill) <- personen
colnames(anwesenheit) <- wochentage
rownames(anwesenheit) <- personen

# Modell
m <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(e[p,g,w], p=1:length(personen), w=1:length(wochentage), g=1:length(geräte), type = "binary") %>% # Einsatzvariable, wer macht wann was, dann=1 , sonst 0 wird nicht eingesetzt
  add_constraint(sum_expr(e[p,g,w],p=1:length(personen))<=1, g=1:length(geräte), w=1:length(wochentage)) %>% # An jedem Wochentag darf auf einem Geräte nur eine Person eingeteilt sein
  add_constraint(sum_expr(e[p,g,w],g=1:length(geräte))<=1, p=1:length(personen), w=1:length(wochentage)) %>% # An jedem Wochentag darf eine Person nur auf einem Gerät eingeteilt sein
  set_objective(sum_expr(e[p,g,w]*skill[p,g]*anwesenheit[p,w], p=1:length(personen), w=1:length(wochentage), g=1:length(geräte)), sense="max") %>% # Offensichtlich?
  solve_model(with_ROI(solver="glpk"))
```

The model is not solved due to an error. It sais:

Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [1]

It has to be a general error that we should be able to find without understanding the model...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I figured I would answer since it was still open. I got this same error with one of my constraints, but I think your issue is in your objective expression. It seems that `ompr` prefers the variable coefficients to be multiplied together before being multiplied by the variable. I ran your listed code and got the same error, but when I set parentheses around the `skill[p,g]*anwesenheit[p,w]`  portion of your set_objective call as below, and the model ran and solved without a problem.

`set_objective(sum_expr(e[p,g,w]*(skill[p,g]*anwesenheit[p,w]), p=1:length(personen), w=1:length(wochentage), g=1:length(geräte)), sense="max") %>% # Offensichtlich?`